# Angular subscribe problems

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

I need to Final Count to always be 1, this is storing the fail request count. I am also unsure as why the Final Count is printed before the Initial Count. I am not understanding the subscribe properly maybe. Hopefully this makes sense.

```
 public failed: number = 0;

    buttonClickMethod(): void {
        // request code

        Observable.onErrorResumeNext(myrequests).first().subscribe(
            () => {
                // On next code
            },
            () => {
                this.failed++;
                console.log('Initial count' + this.failed)
            },
            () => {
                //On completed code
            }
        });
    console.log('Final count' + this.failed)
    this.failed = 0;

    }
```

Comment: Could you include more code of your class?

Comment: Final count is called before initial count, because the myrequests does some async actions (I expect it calls a backend service). The function in the subscribe block is only called after the requests completes. But this only is for the callbacks in the subscribe method. The code after subscribe is executed immediatly.

Comment: Maybe you could fix your problem by moving the console.log statement into the on complete callback. Anyway, it is not very clear what you want to do. Why should the final count be always 1? Are you assuming that the request always fails? Otherwise I would expect the final count to be 0 if the request succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

```
public failed: number = 0;

buttonClickMethod(): void {
    // request code
    Observable.onErrorResumeNext(myrequests).first().subscribe(
        () => {
            // On next code
        },
        () => {
            this.failed++;
            console.log('Initial count' + this.failed)
        },
        () => {
            //On completed code
        }
    });
console.log('Final count' + this.failed)
this.failed = 0;

}
```

Your `console.log` statement is on button click which will get executed immediately, unlike your Observable which is `async` in nature.

Have a look at how async calls work.